# How do I use a variable here?

Tags: lua, roblox

I want it to find LocalPlayers' name, but instead it it doesn't do anything. How can I fix this?

```
plr = game.Players.LocalPlayer.Name
x = Game.Workspace.Living.'plr'.StandMorph.StandSkin.Value
print(x)
```

Comment: The print function is designed to put out on stdout. Game engines using normally another method to print out something on a graphic display . LÖVE for example has: love.graphics.printf()

Answer (score 0):

```lua
local plr = game.Players.LocalPlayer.Name
local x = Game.Workspace.Living.'plr'.StandMorph.StandSkin.Value
print(tostring(plr))
print(tostring(x))
```

And are you sure you are executing the code no random returns or you maybe forgot an callback

Answer (score 0):

To get children with strings, you use brackets.

```
plr = game.Players.LocalPlayer.Name
x = Game.Workspace.Living[plr].StandMorph.StandSkin.Value
print(x)
```